# Need someone to correct my mysql query for table creation

Tags: php

I want to create a table as that I can have in the one variable (going to send it to js later on) and then display it. But result of my echo is only table head ('Produkty', 'Ilość', 'Cena'). Can you show me where I made mistakes or correct me?

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
include "database.php";


 $dane = array();
 $tabela='<table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Produkt</th>
        <th>Ilość</th>
        <th>Cena</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>';
 $dane=array();

 $sql_main="SELECT Products.`Name`,Orders_NEW.`Amount`,((Products.`Price`)*(Orders_NEW.`Amount`)) as 'PRICE' FROM `Orders_NEW` inner join `Products` on Orders_NEW.`Product`=Products.`ID` AND `Order_ID`=669";

 $dane = $db->query($sql_main);

 foreach($dane as $row)
 {
  $tabela.="<tr><td>".$row['Name']."</td><td>".$row['Amount']."</td><td>".$row['Price']."</td></tr>";
 }

 $sql_second="SELECT SUM((Products.`Price`)*(Orders_NEW.`Amount`)) as 'SUMA' FROM `Orders_NEW` inner join `Products` on Orders_NEW.`Product`=Products.`ID`  AND `Order_ID`=669";

 $dane_second= array();

 $dane_second= $db -> query($sql_second);

 foreach($dane_second as $row)
 {

 $tabela.='<thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Łącznie</th>
          <th></th>

        <th>'.$row["SUMA"].'</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
</table>';
 }

 echo($tabela);



 ?>
```

Edited: Changed foreach into while($row = $dane->fetch_assoc())
 Now my result is:

Produkt Ilość   Cena

Łącznie

seems like variables like $row['Name'] etc is the problem here

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php --- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php - Debugging is 50% of the fun.

Comment: make sure that exist a Order with the id 669, you have this `Order_ID=669` in your sql code

Comment: yeah i have Order_ID with id 669, tried sql querry on my sql server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you have some sort of custom class with database.php, but if $db just contains mysqli object then you need to do the following:

```
$dane = $db->query($sql_main);

while($row = $dane->fetch_assoc()) {
    $tabela.="<tr><td>".$row['Name']."</td><td>".$row['Amount']."</td><td>".$row['Price']."</td></tr>";
}
```

Same goes for the second query (this assumes your SQL is correct and returning results by the way).

Comment: it did something, but still doesn't work, updated my post

Comment: Update: Just re-printed querrys and and everything works perfectly. Your Loop helped me a lot. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the code:

```
foreach($dane_second as $row){
    $tabela.='<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Łącznie</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>'.$row["SUMA"].'</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   </table>'; //Here's the problem
}
echo($tabela);
```

Move closing table out of foreach.